any reason to have a more specific title when it risk limiting the scope?
I am deciding between a more general title vs a more specific title.
Since the title can also limit the scope, I cannot think of a reason to use the more specific title?

Found an interesting fact relating to this: "If a satisfactory title is not supplied by the applicant, the examiner may, at the time of allowance, change the title by
an examiner’s amendment". Interesting question whether such an amended title can be used against the patentee.

An overly general title can impede future searchers. Imagine if every patent had the title “Invention” or “Novel Apparatus”.
